# Publish an event with Backbone Mediator from a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mediator

Is it a good practice / pattern to publish events from Backbone models?

Comment: I'm just getting some data by doing an ajax request inside the model and I want to publish an event as soon as its ready to trigger some actions in my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sort answer**: yes

**Long answer**: This is a very good approach to use events: Model is changed by some component and some other is listen to this change and execute a proper action.

This is a very good way of communication between components that have not any relation with each other but a common Model.